# Cannot remove Dismiss and SignUp Button from ParseUI

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I can't see why my loginViewController continues to have the dismiss X and the Signup button.  I don't want either.  I thought by simply not including them in my `logInController.fields` array that they would not appear, but that does not seem to be the case.  Any help?

```
let logInController = PFLogInViewController()
logInController.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(logInController, animated:true, completion: nil)

logInController.fields = [PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword, PFLogInFields.LogInButton, PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten]
```

I am getting an error that might mean something.

```
2015-12-22 21:35:29.463 App Name[5737:99658] Warning: Attempt to present <PFLogInViewController: 0x7fd318c56020> on <app name.loginViewController: 0x7fd318d6c120> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: Are you using the navigation controller ?

Comment: No - there is a navigation controller used on other views on the storyboard, but they are not connected to this loginViewController at all right now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

1. Make sure to import `ParseUI`
2. You must present your viewController in `viewDidAppear` not in `viewDidLoad`.

Here is the code that I am using, it builds and runs fine.

```
class LoginViewController: PFLogInViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let logInController = PFLogInViewController()
    logInController.delegate = self
    logInController.fields = [PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword, PFLogInFields.LogInButton, PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten, PFLogInFields.SignUpButton]
    self.presentViewController(logInController, animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```